# How to associate a new TLS cert with an AWS API gateway domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to replace the TLS certificate associated an API gateway domain name programmatically. I know how to do it using the AWS Console, with the Upload and Rotate options. But I cannot figure out how to do it with either the AWS CLI or the boto3 Python library. I thought that the boto3 update_domain_name() method would work, by using 'replace' opcodes to replace the certificate body, private key, and certificate chain. But when I call the method, I get an error saying that the only value that can be replaced is '/certificateName'. This suggests that I need to upload the new certificate some other way and then use this method to change the name so that it points to the new certificate. How do I upload the certificate?

Comment: Certificates used by various services are always uploaded through [IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs_manage.html).  The console tends to hide this fact, but that's what's happening, and that is likely what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#how-to-rotate-custom-domain-certificate) points out, you cannot rotate the certificate programmatically. You can do it only from API Gateway Console.